# How to extract the name from text in PHP

Tags: php

I want to extract the name from a paragraph or text content. I am using PHP. I tried to extract the name from below library.

https://packagist.org/packages/php-text-analysis/php-text-analysis

https://packagist.org/packages/php-text-analysis/php-text-analysis

```
    $text = "my name is maneesh, and my friend name is Paritosh";
    $freqDist = freq_dist(tokenize($text));
    print_r($freqDist); die;
```

My expected output is : maneesh, Paritosh

Actual result is getting only frequency of word:

```
   (
        [my] => 2
        [name] => 2
        [is] => 2
        [maneesh] => 1
        [and] => 1
        [friend] => 1
        [Paritosh] => 1
    )
```

Comment: How is the code supposed to know if it's a name or a 'thing'? `my name is Paris`, `I live in Paris, France` both is Paris but only one is a name. Edit: OK, technically `Paris, France` is also a name but I assume that is not what is requested here.

Comment: If you know the names always start with capital letters then you can quite easily create a list of possible names. But that would of course also include `Paris, France, Microsoft` and so on.

Comment: @Andreas I am talking about "name".  and I want to get the name from text. The text can be only "Maneesh" or "my name is maneesh"

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the library you mentioned, you have to train your model. That means, fill them with many possible ways in which people can say their name. But even so, I wouldn't be perfect (depends on how well you trained your model).

Moreover, you are getting only frequency of words because that's the analysis you requested with the method `freq_dist`. I think you have to use corpus analysis for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the replying Carter. But I am looking for any Natural processing language to detect the word such as name.